# How hiding the SMS number really works?

Tags: android, sms

I'm working in a web application and it has to include some send SMS feature; I'm planning to create an Android Application and use it to send SMS taking data from the server. The customer asked if the phone number can be hidden, I really couldn't answer the question; So that's pretty much my research this days. How hiding the phone number from a SMS works? Is it something with the provider or can the SMS number really be hidden or spoofed?

Greetings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually this is done by the SMSC.  There are several online services that allow you to specify a "sender" value.  This could be a word, rather than a number.  Some companies, like banks do this (i.e: "Citibank", "HSBC", ...).

For example, using a popular SMS service such as Twilio, they [allow](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223133967-Changing-the-sender-ID-for-sending-SMS-messages) you to set the sender ID, number or word.  Obviously with necessary restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

When I had to do something similar but on a more theoretical level I used something similar to this http://www.thebitbag.com/how-to-hide-your-phone-number-when-sending-a-text-message-on-your-phone/80814 but i think your best bet would be calling your provider.

P.s cant create a hyperlink for some reason, sorry

Answer (score 1):

Actually another option is to send MMS - you can add the header **X-Mms-Sender-Visibility** and set it to hide (0x80) if you can craft the PDU.